# Why is `Into` not Send/Sync?

Tags: rust

From this line:

```
fn b<A>(a: A, b: Copy + Into<A>) {}
```

I'm getting the error `non-Send/Sync additional trait`, pointing to the `Into<B>` bit. If I remove it, it compiles. If I change the definition to take an additional type parameter that satisfies both traits, it also compiles.

```
fn a<A, B: Copy + Into<A>>(a: A, b: B) {}
```

Comment: It's generally an [`MVCE`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) in your question, along with the full error from the compiler. Ideally this should all work if dropped into https://play.rust-lang.org/. There isn't really enough to go on as-is.

Comment: Does that help at all?

Comment: Nothing about your example code would trigger errors about `Sync` / `Send`, so presumable there is more code that needs to be included.

Comment: My bad, examples were inverted. The first line gives out the error even in play.rust-lang

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that the full error message is this:

```
error[E0225]: only Send/Sync traits can be used as additional traits in a trait object
 --> src/main.rs:1:25
  |
1 | fn b<A>(a: A, b: Copy + Into<A>) {}
  |                         ^^^^^^^ non-Send/Sync additional trait
```

This error message is not making a statement about whether `Into<A>` implements `Send` or `Sync`; it is saying that the trait `Into<A>` is *itself* not either of those traits.

The compiler is telling you this because the compiler is assuming that you are deliberately attempting to create a *trait object* with multiple traits.

- Typical examples of *trait objects* are things like `Box<Trait>` or `&Trait`. You happen to have written your code without any indirection before the trait itself, which is not supported (at least not in Rust today), but the compiler is treating your code as if your type declaration `b: Copy + Into<A>` *is* a trait object, and then finding problems that arise after making such an assumption.
- You can read more about trait objects in [the book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch17-02-trait-objects.html)
- If you write your code with only one trait in the trait object, e.g. `b: std::fmt::Debug`, then the compiler will give you a different error:

  ```
  error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::fmt::Debug + 'static: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
   --> src/main.rs:1:15
    |
  1 | fn b<A>(a: A, b: std::fmt::Debug) {}
    |               ^ `std::fmt::Debug + 'static` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
    |
    = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `std::fmt::Debug + 'static`
    = note: all local variables must have a statically known size
  ```

*Anyway*, in Rust today, you cannot generally put multiple traits into a single "trait object". But there is one exceptional case: you can currently use `Send` and/or `Sync` as additional traits in a trait object.

So the compiler is telling you that your attempt to use `Into<A>` as an additional trait in the trait object is invalid, because you can only have `Send` or `Sync` as an additional trait, and `Into<A>` is not either of those.

Comment: That is perfect, thanks. I'm still getting used to the compiler so I'm seeing myself getting confused about its messages s more often than I'd like. Awesome answer, thanks.